# How do I convert this multi-dimentional associative array to json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a loop that creates an associative array in js that I need to convert to json.

Javascript:

```
var guest = {};
var guests = {};

for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
  var name = GetName();
  var email = GetEmail();
  guest = { 'Email': email, 'Name': name };
  guests.push(guest);
}
```

End of the loop would give me, say:

```
{
 {'Email':"bob@zyz.com", 'Name':"Mr. Bob"},
 {'Email':"tom@zyz.com", 'Name':"Mr. Tom"}
}
```

How can I convert this to JSON? (OK with small jquery plugin)

I need to pass this json array to my MVC 3 controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddGuests(List<SelectedGuest> guests){

}

public class SelectedGuest
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: There is no such thing as associative array in JavaScript. There are objects, and **JSON** is _JavaScript Object Notation_ [read more](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need square brackets if you want to deal with arrays. In javascript there are really two artifacts: objects (`{}`) and arrays of objects (`[]`) and the distinction is really important:

```
var guest = { };
var guests = [ ];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var name = GetName();
    var email = GetEmail();
    guest = { 'Email': email, 'Name': name };
    guests.push(guest);
}
```

Now that we have fixed your javascript let's use AJAX to send this `guests` array to the `AddGuests` controller action:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/SomeController/AddGuests',
    data: JSON.stringify(guests),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json', // <-- Make sure to set the proper content type
    success: function(result) {
        // TODO: handle the results of the controller action
    }
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method shown here is implemented in most modern browsers but for older browsers you might want to include the [following script](http://www.json.org/js.html).

One last remark:

Never hardcode urls in javascript like this:

```
url: '/SomeController/AddGuests'
```

Always use Url helpers in ASP.NET MVC when dealing with urls, like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("AddGuests", "SomeController")'
```

Comment: @Projapati, no, nothing to do with jquery. As I said in my answer it is built-in javascript function in modern browsers, and it is a good practice to include the script I've linked to so that older browsers work as well. As far as *older* browsers are concerned, everything that is not the current latest version is old. Examples: IE 8, FireFox 3.0, ... So to be sure simply include the script in your page: it is intelligent and does browser feature detection and if the browser supports the function it simply uses the native method.

Comment: how is url: '@Url.Action("AddGuests", "SomeController")' safer or better?

Comment: @Projapati, for example let's suppose that you have hardcoded the url as shown. Now your application will work perfectly fine in development under Cassini. Then you will deploy your application in IIS. But in IIS there's probably a virtual directory, so the correct url will be `/NameOfVirtualDirectory/SomeController/AddGuests`. Because you have hardcoded the url your application simply won't work and return a 404 error in production. So: absolutely never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application, always use Url helpers as they will take into account such scenarios.

Comment: Where is the minified version of the script? I see multiple js files here https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: @Projapati, I don't think there is a minified version available. You can minify it yourself using one of the many tools out there. For example at the end of the article there is one such tool: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Answer (score 1):

After your for loop call `JSON.stringify();`

```
var json = JSON.stringify(guests);
```